# What is the use of "if(window.execScript)" check performed in javascript?

Tags: javascript, vbscript

I have a javascript code block that looks like this:

```
if (window.execScript)
{
    window.execScript("myDateVar = FormatDateTime(Now, 2)", "vbscript")
}
else
{
    var my_date_var = new Date();
    myDateVar = my_date_var.toLocaleDateString();
}
```

I understand window.execScript is used to execute a script in a specified language... in my case, vbscript. But what is the purpose of the **if(window.execScript)** check performed?

Comment: Just to check if that method exists, as it is not the case in all browsers/browser versions

Comment: @Bartdude Thank you. Your comment and mplungjan's input answered my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a defensive coding technique called [Object Detection](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/support.html)

It tests if a certain feature is available before using it. In this case the `execScript` (and especially `vbscript`) is not avaiable in all browsers and will get a workaround

Comment: Thank you. You have answered my question.